# How to save highscore and load highscore in a cocos2d iphone game

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have made my first iPhone game and i have it in the beta testing stage, but then i realised i am missing high score. I don't know how to add high score into the game and if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated, also could you tell me if it goes in the game scenes .m or .h file and where to declare it cheers.
Also i have tried to do this before and failed.

Comment: You could use `NSUserDefaults` to store your high score.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is using game center. It's very simple to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

1. First way: look at the plist this is the best way to store highscore load whatever your highScore into `Plist` and then retrieve that highscore from plist whenever you need. Look at this tutorial: [Look at this tutorial](http://hayageek.com/plist-tutorial/)
2. Second way is to store your highscore into `NSUSerDefault` and retrieve when you want.

NSuserDefault only vanish when you delete the app from simulator or device. So this is also solution for you..

Look at this

Save data to default:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [def setObject:highScore forKey:@"High Score"];
        [def synchronize];
```

Comment: Do i put this in my game scenes .m file? also where do i put it? in the init? and what other code do i need to save it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Use `NSUserDefaults`
- Use `plist`s
- Use `CoreData`

If it is just a numerical value you want to store, `defaults` and `plist` are fine. But in case you want to store high scores, names, times, and/or scores of many/other users, et cetera, I would suggest using `CoreData`.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Takes some work, but when it's done, you'll be glad you used it.

Answer (score 0):

To save some data :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:yourNumber forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

to read it :

```
int high=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"HighScore"];
```

This is objective c, cocos2d does not have some special way to save the data for you .
You better not use the game center only, but keep some copy at the user defaults .

Comment: So this is the only code i need? where do  i put this code? in the init?